# Rails + Watir. Selenium - can't run more then 4 chrome instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, watir, selenium-chromedriver

I'm have a parser based on Rails, Watir and chromedriver.

Parsers runs every minute with new chrome instance. Each instance has different proxy server. It takes 5-6minutes to finish 1 parse task.

So there could be up to 6 chrome instances at the same time. The problem is, that chromedriver isn't responding after trying to spawn 5th instance and it kills all of chrome process.

It looks like that

```
13:00 - parse start - chromes=1
13:01 - parse start - chromes=2
13:02 - parse start - chromes=3
13:03 - parse start - chromes=4
13:04 - parse start - chrome crashes, all instances killed, chromes=0
13:05 - parse start - chromes=1
```

Log File:

```
08/13 - 02:47 [1407890822] -- !! chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=36.0.1985.143)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267518,platform=Linux 3.13.0-30-generic x86_64)
08/13 - 02:47 [1407890762] -- !! chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=36.0.1985.143)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267518,platform=Linux 3.13.0-30-generic x86_64)
08/13 - 02:47 [1407890702] -- !! chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=36.0.1985.143)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267518,platform=Linux 3.13.0-30-generic x86_64)
```

Tried to use Firefox instead, but it had same problem, browser was crashing after spawning process #4

Code, that spawning browser

```
headless = Headless.new(display: 100, reuse: true, destroy_at_exit: false)
headless.start

proxy_serv = ProxyServer.order(last_use: :asc).first
proxy_address = "#{proxy_serv.ip}:#{proxy_serv.port}"

$browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :switches => ["--proxy-server=#{proxy_address}"]
proxy_serv.update_attribute('last_use', DateTime.now)
```

---

```
OS: Ubuntu
RAM: 32GB
PROC: Intel® Core™ i7-4770
```

System load during parse run - 2%

Comment: i guess system isnt powerful enough to allocate required resources so it is crashing.

Comment: The system has 32GB of RAM, system load is 2.4% during the spawn of browser #5

Comment: i can spawn $browsers^n on my debian machine. I wonder whats going on. Have you tried upgrading your gems?

Comment: @Duck1337 could u pls you try this?

100.times {Thread.new { 
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
b.goto 'http://google.com'
puts b.title
}}

Comment: worked just fine. 100.times{Thread.new{ b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome ; b.goto 'google.com'; puts b.title}} I'm running vanilla Debian 64 - 7.6.0 with xfce 4.8. core i3 8gb ram.

Comment: It seems that the problem is in system overload. Currently I switched from chromes to :phantomjs since it uses less cpu/ram and it crashes up to ~10 times every hour.

uptime commands says: load average: 1.29, 1.41, 1.41

I guess the solution would be to rent separate server for my webdrivers.

Also, what is your system load during the run of that test?

Answer (score -1):

I hear if you trigger a popup via javascript, you can then access the extra windows using the `windows` method, then goto, etc. Kind of sloppy though